# Como mostrar un mensaje con Toast dentro de un Thread en Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, hilos

Resulta que al querer mostrar un mensaje por Toast y mandarle el contexto me sale un error, lo hago así:

```
 public void mostrarMascotas(){
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                Connection con = new Conexion().getConexion();
                Statement stm = con.createStatement();
                ResultSet rs = stm.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM tbl_mascota");
                String cadena = "";
                while (rs.next()){
                    cadena += rs.getString("mascota_nombre")+"\n";
                }
                Toast.makeText(this, cadena, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();// Aqui me sale el error
            }
            catch (Exception exp) {
                System.out.println("Error al conectarse con la BD: "+ exp.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }).start();
}
```

en el Toast al cambiar el contexto `this` por `getApplicationContext()` ya no me tira error, pero al correr la aplicación y ejecuto este método se me cierra la aplicación....

Lo raro esta que al sustituir el `Toask.makeText`  por un System.out.println(cadena) me funciona perfectamente y me obtiene los datos que necesito de la Base de Datos.

Comment: Ponlo así: `runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                 public void run() {
Toast.makeText(TuClaseActivity.this,"texto",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });` Y no pongas `this`dentro del `makeText()` sino `TuClaseActivity.this...` Aunque me pregunto si el  `new Thread(new Runnable() {` del principio **¿es sólo a causa del `Toast`?**

Comment: Evitemos el uso de la etiqueta `error`. Está en proceso de "quemado", más detalles en https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1738/65

Comment: el contexto cógelo de GetContextApplication des de el servicio.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Si defines como contexto `this` para crear el `Toast`, el problema es que el contexto intentará ser el propio Thread, es recomendable en este caso usar el contexto de la aplicación mediante [**getApplicationContext()**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getApplicationContext()).

```
// Toast.makeText(this, cadena, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();// Aqui me sale el error
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), cadena, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

> [**getApplicationContext()**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getApplicationContext()) : Devuelve el contexto del objeto
>   Application global único del proceso actual.

Puedes usar también el contexto de la `Activity` en caso de que tengas acceso:

```
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,cadena, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

pero es más ligero usar [**getApplicationContext()**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getApplicationContext()).

---

> Como mostrar un mensaje con Toask dentro de un Thread en Android
>   Studio?

Existen varias maneras de mostrar un `Toast` durante la ejecución de un `Thread`, por ejemplo, mediante un `Handler` o mediante `runOnUiThread()`. Como ejemplo:

```
   runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                           //Toast.makeText(this, cadena, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();// Aqui me sale el error     
                           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),cadena, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    });
```

Con esto no tendrás problema para mostrar el `Toast` durante la ejecución de un `Thread`.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

Answer (score 1):

Buenas.

Creo que tu solución es correr el toast dentro del Thread de Ui, de la siguiente forma:

```
miActividad.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        Toast.makeText(miActividad, cadena, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

Según la documentacion de [runOnUiThread](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread(java.lang.Runnable)):

> Runs the specified action on the UI thread. If the current thread is the UI thread, then the action is executed immediately. If the current thread is not the UI thread, the action is posted to the event queue of the UI thread.

En español :

> Ejecuta la acción especificada en el subproceso de la interfaz de usuario. Si el subproceso actual es el subproceso de UI, la acción se ejecuta inmediatamente. Si el subproceso actual no es el subproceso de UI, la acción se ubica en la cola de eventos del subproceso de UI.

Tu código debería queda mas o menos así:

```
public void mostrarMascotas(){
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                /** operaciones */
                ClaseActividad.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                       Toast.makeText(miActividad, cadena, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                   }
                });
            }
            catch (Exception exp) {
                System.out.println("Error al conectarse con la BD: "+ exp.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }).start();
}
```